# After transfering data using Socket.io emit, how could I release the data in memory?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, memory-leaks, socket.io

For some reason, after using socket.emit(), the data is still in memory, according to Chrome's dev tool. Since I have to use this line of code for many times, the memory usage keep raising.
My JS code on client :

```
socket.emit('upload',{data: a_very_long_string});
```

Comment: Is it a seriously impeding your work or just for knowledge? Can you put your findings in the question, like how much memory is it eating up.

Comment: Actually, it is impeding my work cuz I am trying to building a game that use websocket as the way for transfering data. It is like everytime I use emit to upload an 2M image, it eats 2M(not exactly, but it is shown in the curve of dev tool of chrome). But I would like my game to run for couple of hours without crashing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Local variable (declare with `var`) in JS is garbage collected automatically when the function return. And if it was a global variable, you can always release it by `delete`. So I guess in your case, it is because some global variable is not released after `emit()`.

I found this post talking about memory leak in Socket.IO, which could be helpful in your case. http://jpallen.net/2013/03/08/tracking-down-a-memory-leak-in-node-js-and-socket-io/

About releasing variables, you can refer to this question: [Memory release from local variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681511/memory-release-from-local-variable-in-javascript).

Comment: No.I am pretty sure it is not the issue in my js code. The following cold would not raise my memory usage :   var a="very......long"; socket.emit('upload',{});  but if I use : var a="very...long"; socket.emit('upload',{a:a});, my memory usage goes really high. Also, i am asking about the memory usage of browser, not in node.js.

Comment: The socket.io is the same project that mentioned in the post as in the chrome. Anyway they run on V8, no matter you run it in node or chrome. The memory leak is not from your code, but it is in the socket module.

Comment: but need to know whether it is a socket.io's issue or the V8's. If it is V8's, I could switch to FF or even IE, cuz my problem is the crash of browser. If it is from socket.io, my could try to other websocket library.

Comment: Seems like there is no good solution for my issue. But have to give you the credit

Answer (score 0):

That is a problem with socket.io. It is because of memory leak in websocket server.

See the solution posted here :

1. http://jpallen.net/2013/03/08/tracking-down-a-memory-leak-in-node-js-and-socket-io/
2. https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1015