# Deleting variable from memory node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, memory-management

I know, that, for example, c++ has something like `delete variable` and it will be deleted from the memory. Is there something like this in JS.
For example, I have `var canSendRequest = true;` and after some operations I want to delete it totally from the memory. As I read, `delete canSendRequest` will not work properly, but I did not manage to find a properly working way. Does someone know, how to do that?

Comment: JavaScript is garbage collected. If there are no references to the variable, it will go away by itself.

Comment: As Barmar mentioned, There's garbage collector like in other programming languages, so any variable, when not used anymore, is collected.

If you want to actively do so, you can give it undefined (or null) value ```myVar = undefined```

Comment: `delete canSendRequest` will work removing the variable from the current context. What do you mean with "will not work properly"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory release from local variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681511/memory-release-from-local-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: So, if I make sth like this:
```
var v = 1;
//some code with v
//some code without v
```
The V variable will be automatically deleted after the part "hidden" behing the first // line

Comment: @F.Igor: It won't. That's not what `delete` does in JS. It *sort of* works with globals under some circumstances, but that's all.

Comment: See also [How to unset a JavaScript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1596782/215552). The variable will not be "automatically deleted" so much as "scheduled to be removed if the runtime can determine it will not be used again".

Comment: `Does this answer your question? Memory release from local variable in JavaScript `
I did not understand the only thing: if the variable is not inside any functions/collectors/prototypes and so on. It is just declared on the first line of the code, will it be totally forgooten after using delete

Comment: `How to unset a JavaScript variable?.` I have seen that and that is why I ask this question: I want to delete the variable that is declared using var outside all functions

Comment: You can't delete a global variable declared with `var`. Also, garbage collector doesn't collect any global variables nevertheless it is used later or not. The solution is not to use global variables at all, everything else is traced and unused variables are removed automatically by GC.

Answer (score 1):

Since JS is garbage collected, you don't have direct control over the release of memory.

You just have to wait for the runtime to free the memory, which it will *if* there are no permanent references to it via the global object or a permanently existing closure. In those cases, you need to eliminate such references to the variable so that it qualifies to be freed.

If you're saying you want to eliminate the identifier itself from the scope, you definitely can't unless it was a global that was set as a property of the global object, not using proper variable declaration syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Var is **Hoisting** type use let or const. like  `var g_a = 1; //create with var, g_a is a variable  delete g_a; //return false console.log(g_a); //g_a is still 1`

now try with let and const

Comment: `let` and `const` are "hoisted" as well, and `delete` operator is not purposed to delete variables, "_g\_a is still 1_" nevertheless what declaration type you'd use here.

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, their is still **no way** to clear, control, or modify garbage. Node.js automatically controls memory management and free space.

**Note: It only clears those spaces that are no longer used by the program.**

In some cases, you may need to modify or clear your memory, and therefore you must modify your codes and restructure them so that you don't need to control or clear your memory. As example, look at this scenario:

In runtime, their is an array declaration like this:

```
const arr = [2,3,4,5];
```

Now, in some operation, you need to add `1` at the beginning. Although you can do that by using the `Array.unshift` method but this will make a reference to your real array, and `1` will be attached **forever**.

To avoid this kind of garbage collection, you can use the spread (`...`) operator. Ex:

```
const newArr = [1,...arr]
```